# Windows 10 won't hibernate

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

My setting is display off after 15 min, sleep after 60 min and hibernate after 120 min.
Just moving mouse won't wake up the computer, but keyboard typing and mouse clicking would do.

This setting has worked for long time (several month). 
Maybe from the last update (12/15) or from the new year, my computer won't hibernate at all.
Display goes off after specified time, but it won't sleep or hibernate.

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this problem will occur if you are running certain software in the background.

IE:

Backup Software
Remote Desktop Software

I have seen this specific problem with both of these type of applications because the software will override the power settings in Windows.

You should look to see what applications you have installed since the last time you remember it working.  Once you identify those you should look for things that would potentially want the computer to not sleep. (this should be somewhat obvious) And disable them in startup.

Additionally you could open task manager and go to startup and disable startup applications until you are sure it is working again.

Comment: This did not help in my situation. I even did a Windows 10 reset (which uninstalls applications and drivers) but still when choosing "Hibernate" from Start menu it seems to just switch off the screen and/or sleep, but doesn't fully hibernate (wasting battery).

Comment: Have you checked your bios settings you could have this over ridden in the power management settings

Answer (score 0):

An update or application may have disabled *hibernate*. Re-enable *hibernate* from the command line. Start a CMD session as Administrator and enter

> powercfg -h on

That should fix the issue.

Comment: This did not help in my situation. Hibernate is enabled in Control Panel, but when choosing it from Start menu it seems to just switch off the screen and/or sleep, but doesn't fully hibernate (wasting battery).

Answer (score -1):

updating the motherboard BIOS worked for me trust me ive done all i could find on google updating BIOS is the one to go if you have nothing else to do

Comment: I honestly don't understand how come a question that was asked three years ago can pop up again today, but hibernation failing to happen usually means your chipset won't support it, or you're short on free space on your system drive, or the size of your hiberfil.sys hibernation file is too small, and it takes too much time for Windows to effectively compress the content of the RAM before copying it to disk. In that case, a "powercfg hibernate size 100" command as admin usually does the trick, to the expense of a little free space, because there won't be any compression prior to copying.